# skip file headers in matlab

Tags: matlab

My file format is *.Vt2 , It' strong ground motion record.
  It can be download  at http://peer.berkeley.edu/smcat/search.html
  choose a earthquake then download the record of  any station .Data like this:

**PEER STRONG MOTION DATABASE RECORD. PROCESSING BY PACIFIC ENGINEERING.

TAIWAN SMART1 (45) 11/14/86, SMART1 C00, EW

VELOCITY TIME HISTORY IN UNITS OF CM/S. FILTER POINTS: HP=0.1 Hz LP=25.0 Hz

NPTS=  4000, DT= .01000 SEC

  .9437205E-03   .1497919E-01   .3328475E-01   .5111011E-01   .6865002E-01

  .8659123E-01   .9975034E-01   .1072606E+00   .1168364E+00   .1217983E+00

  .1135203E+00   .8993586E-01   .6435175E-01   .3819334E-01   .1840042E-01**

What I want to do is skip the 4 headerlines and read the numbers (by row),then save them in a
N×1 matrix M.  But I don't know how to make it.
   Any help is  greet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
x=importdata('filename.txt');
```

Your data will be:

```
x.data
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might try this:

```
fid = fopen(filename,'r');
A = textscan(fid,'%f%f%f%f%f','Delimiter',',','headerLines',4);
data = cat(2,A{:});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Nice ， Very time when I ask one question ,My repution get -1,

Comment: It's because the other users would appreciate to see first what you've done on your own. It's a way to be polite with the community showing your own effort.

Comment: oh, Thanks, I just realize this ,I will better next time